# filter varbinary field by length

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am storing ips using `VARBINARY(16)` data type. I'd like to select just the ipv4 ips. Is it possible to filter column by the lenght used in `VARBINARY` (or `VARCHAR`)? Something like this

```
SELECT INET6_NTOA(`ip`) from TABLE where BYTESLENGHT(`ip`) = 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ip_n` is the "numeric" version, then

```
LENGTH(ip_n)
```

will be 16 for IPv6 and something smaller for IPv4.

```
mysql> SELECT LENGTH(INET_ATON('11.22.33.44')) AS v4,
              LENGTH(INET6_ATON('f::f')) AS v6;
+------+------+
| v4   | v6   |
+------+------+
|    9 |   16 |
+------+------+
```

If you were starting a string ("A"), this will be true (non-zero) for `ip_a` (string version) if it is IPv6, or false (zero) for IPv4:

```
LOCATE(':', ip_a)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [IS_IPV4](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/is_ipv4/) function as a mechanism too.

So:

```
SELECT INET6_NTOA(ip)
FROM TABLE
WHERE IS_IPV4(INET6_NTOA(ip))
```

Note MariaDB-10.5 has a [INET6](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/inet6) data type too.